# Cambiar color del ítem seleccionado en un menú de Blogger

Tags: menú

He seguido varios de los ejemplos de [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4999/c%C3%B3mo-resaltar-un-elemento-seleccionado-en-un-men%C3%BA#new-answer?newreg=61cb5d083f00423b8ec71a77864c5411) post, pero no ha funcionado en *Blogger* al momento de cambiar la almohadilla (*#*) por una *URL*.

Inserté lo siguiente en el `<head>` del documento.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
```

Además, inserté el *HTML* en un *gatget*:

```
<div id="main">
<ul>
    <li><a id="inicio" href="http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a id="nosotros" href="http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/p/pagina1">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
    <li><a id="producto" href="http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/p/pagina2">Producto</a></li>
    <li><a id="contacto" href="http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/search/label/etiqueta1">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Todo lo demás lo dejé como estaba.

Por otro lado, el siguiente *script*, también lo inserté dentro del `head`:

```
$(function() {
  $("#main ul li a").click(function() {
    // quitar .seleccionado a todos (por si hay alguno)
    $("#main ul li a").removeClass("seleccionado");
    // agregar seleccionado a "este" elemento.
    $(this).addClass("seleccionado");
  });
});
```

Utilizo este blog para probar: http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/

Comment: Tienes que quitar la almohadilla del href

Comment: Ya lo se, pero olvidé hacerlo cuando pegué el código aquí. Gracias, Alvaro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que al cliquear el enlace estás re-iniciando el estado del sitio, por lo que cualquier cambio realizado se pierde, existen dos formas de evitar la perdida del estado del sitio y son las siguientes

1. Inferencia  es posible a través de algún método saber el éstado
   anterior.
2. Indicarle al navegador que guarde el estado (Cookies, LocalStorage, Session Storage, etc)

En este caso como los enlaces redirigen al mismo sitio, es posible utilizar la inferencia.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
<ul>
    <li><a id="inicio" href="http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a id="nosotros" href="http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/p/pagina1">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
    <li><a id="producto" href="http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/p/pagina2">Producto</a></li>
    <li><a id="contacto" href="http://bpbmsm.blogspot.pe/search/label/etiqueta1">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

y agregas el siguiente script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var menu_entries = $('#main li a');
  menu_entries.each(function(){
    if(this.href==window.location.href){
      $(this.parentElement).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

El script lo que hace es que compara la dirección actual del sitio, y si es igual a la de algún enlace, entonces le agregará la clase "active" al elemento `<li>`, por lo que tu puedes personalizar facilmente el elemento activo con CSS

```
#main li.active { 
  background-color : red  /*elemento activo */
}


#main li{ 
  background-color : blue /* elemento normal */
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, Eduen, pero no funciona.

Comment: en el html que expusiste al principio, el html utiliza el identificador `main`  pero en tu sitio utilizas `menu`, veo que el css lo has cambiado perfectamente, pero se te olvidó hacer lo mismo en el código

`var menu_entries = $('#menu li a');`

Comment: En el blog, tanto el script como el HTML tienen el identificador 'menu'. Y aún así sigue sin funcionar. :/ ¿Crees que las direcciones URL relativas sean el problema? Es decir, no uso enlaces externos.

Comment: Probablemnte, el código lo probé desde firefox incrustando directamente el script, y el código funciona como debería.

Comment: ¿Existe algún método para llegar a lo que quiero?