# No me funciona este script

Tags: javascript, css

Soy aprendiz y voy buscando como puedo. Llevaba tiempo tratando de resaltar los elementos del menú y me encontré en vuestra página.
   He tomado un script de hace unos años y no me funciona. Llevo dándole muchas vueltas y por fin me decido a preguntar. 
   Lo tomé de esta discusión
[¿Cómo resaltar un elemento seleccionado en un menú?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4999/c%C3%B3mo-resaltar-un-elemento-seleccionado-en-un-men%C3%BA)
   Lo tengo en una página pero no consigo resaltar el elemento del menú.

https://www.fibrart.eu/active/index.php
  Está todo el código js y css en el html.
Gracias de antemano.
Saludos.
Caminante.

Comment: Tus páginas actividades, lugar y contacto no tienen el mismo código JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

El código de [¿Cómo resaltar un elemento seleccionado en un menú?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4999/c%C3%B3mo-resaltar-un-elemento-seleccionado-en-un-men%C3%BA) solo funciona para paginas donde el href="#"

En tu caso como hay un redireccionamiento a otras paginas, debes aplicar el estilo desde que carga la página, una forma facil es la siguiente:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var elem_activo = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="' + location.pathname.split("/")[2] + '"]')[0];
    elem_activo.className = elem_activo.className+"seleccionado";
});
</script>
```

Agrega este código a cada una de tus paginas `index.php`, `lugar.php`, `actividades.php` y `contacto.php`

Comment: Hola, Junior Usca: Gracias por la atención y la ayuda. He colocado el script tal como me dices y no termina de funcionar. Lo que quiero es que, al estar en una página del menú, aparezca en el menún marcado con rojo, por ejemplo. Un saludo. Jesús María.

Comment: Hola, vi que colocaste el codigo en el head, para que funcione alli acabo de modificarlo y agregar un listener a DOMContentLoaded, para que asi el codigo se ejecute cuando la pagina haya cargado, pruebalo y veras como funciona. Tambien note que en index.php tienes 2 etiquetas script
`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<script>`
Solo deberias tener 1

Comment: ¡Uf!, perdona pero sigue sin funcionarme. Es verdad que se me había colado la etiqueta duplicada. La eliminé en algunas pero se me escapó en index. He modificado el código pero sigo sin ver el resultado. Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Comment: Error mio, me falto un parentesis al final, pruebalo

Comment: Desde luego. Gracias, Junior Usca. Ahora sí que funciona. Saludos y agradecido de nuevo.